# prevent whole page from flickering when clicking on links

Tags: asp.net, refresh, postback, dotnetnuke, flicker

If you look at  http://www.sportsdirect.com you will see that when you click on a category whole pages doesnt get refereshed, ie you dont notice any flicker, content above menu doesn't get repainted.

How do i achieve that? Is it only speed or something else? My site locally works fine (most of the time, but sportsdirect gets slight flicker sometimes). Online page gets "refreshed", ie there is 300ms when there is gray screen.

This is something that is very important for a client and i dont know how to fix it.

Comment: Every link I've clicked on SportsDirect results in a full page refresh and the URL changes. If you want to change the content on the page without that happening, you'll need to look at making AJAX calls with custom modules, ultimately creating the effect of an SPA as suggested in the answers/comments you've already received.

Comment: If I use chrome as you probably are you are right, whole page does get repainted. I used Firefox. In this topic they also came to the wrong conclusion that these sites use ajax: http://forums.asp.net/t/1616475.aspx?How+to+avoid+page+flicker+when+clicking+on+a+link

Answer (score 0):

You should look into AJAX. This allows you to update parts of your page without refreshing the whole page. This will often reduce or eliminate flicker since it does not rebuild the entire page.

A good place to start is [Here](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/)

Comment: I'm familiar with ajax but that is only solution for chaning content of one page. My problem is transition between two different pages. I'm pretty sure I can't use AJAX for that.

Comment: If you want to avoid flicker between pages, you want to dive into the new world of... SPA (Single Page Apps)  http://www.asp.net/single-page-application

Comment: I don't think SPA is the solution. there are many sites that dont refresh between pages and they are not spa. Btw im using DotNetNuke. Page doesnt refresh if i navigate between empty pages, thats what i wanna achieve. they also dont referesh if i navigate between pages locally. must be some server setting or something.